# Mapping Project Headers to Cocoapods header_files

Tags: cocoapods

I have an existing old framework that I’m trying to get to build with Cocoapods. If currently there are Project header files, should those be included in public_header_files, private_header_files or none at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon what type of access is needed by the framework's clients. From the [docs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#public_header_files), [docs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#private_header_files):

**public_header_files**
A list of file patterns that should be used as public headers.

These are the headers that will be exposed to the user’s project and from which documentation will be generated. When the library is built, these headers will appear in the build directory. If no public headers are specified then all the headers in source_files are considered public.

**private_header_files**
A list of file patterns that should be used to mark private headers.

These patterns are matched against the public headers (or all the headers if no public headers have been specified) to exclude those headers which should not be exposed to the user project and which should not be used to generate the documentation. When the library is built, these headers will appear in the build directory.

Header files that are not listed as neither public nor private will be treated as private, but in addition will not appear in the build directory at all.